# Bower и Windows

Tags: git, bower

Работаю локально над проектом (есть удаленный репозиторий на Bitbucket).

Нужно добавить библиотеку [bitium-bootstrap-colorpicker](https://github.com/bitium/bootstrap-colorpicker).

Какая последовательность действий чтобы эта библиотека прикрепилась к проекту в репозитории (локально можно и так скопировать).

Comment: Верно ли я понимаю, что вы используете [Bower](http://bower.io/) и это какая-то система автоматического развертывания?

Comment: @NickVolynkin,да-сборшик библиотек фронтенда. Подобное есть и для бэка-composer,в проекте они есть(библиотеки уже добаленны через них), но самому добавлять не приходилось..